# How Log accelerometer Value

Tags: android, logging, accelerometer

What's the best way to log accelerometer values?

I wrote a program that gets the accelerometer and uses a clock calculates the velocity and acceleration of the phone. Is it possible the store all these values in a .csv file every 0.1 < x <1 second. Or is there a better options to logging these numbers. How big will the file be?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered some kind of SQL, and try to consider how long the data needs to be stored for, and also where the data needs to be stored. For example you could have a private server setup with the data being sent to it, and any data that is older than a week old gets deleted.

Comment: I want to make the file accessible to users, so it can be opened on excel or any other spread sheet software. However im wondering if there is a more efficient option of storage. Otherwise I would have to keep a file open as long as the program is running. I don't know how much space that takes. My values actively show up on the screen.

Comment: If you want it to be manipulated or viewed it will change your storage options. You could have it stored in a light weight .txt and make your own reader and writer that writes down values on every line and have an indicator to what the line is representing, for example you could have it layed out like this
time:x
velocity:x
acceleration:x
and so on. Once the Time flag is called the reader would see that its a new lot of data. But if you want it to be manipulated with graphs or something, Sql can be loaded in Excel, here is a link on how to do it http://tinyurl.com/bzs6zzs
hope this helps.